# Error when compiling: ::strcmp has not been declared

Tags: linux, makefile

I am using a software called supersense tagger and I have a makefile which is pasted below.

```
#Makefile for sst-light

    CXX = g++
    CFLAGS = -g -O1 -DPIC -fPIC -ILIB -I.

    CXXFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -fno-exceptions
    #CXXFLAGS = -g
    #LIB = -lm ${TAO_LIB} ${PETSC_SNES_LIB}
    #include ${TAO_DIR}/bmake/tao_common

    SOURCES = sst-light.cc \
LIB/utils/utils.cc \
LIB/stats/stats.cc \
LIB/results/results.cc \
LIB/evaluate/evaluate.cc \
LIB/Chain/Chain.cc  \
LIB/Perceptron/Perceptron.cc  \
LIB/tagger_light/Tlight.cc \
LIB/examples/examples.cc \
LIB/features/features.cc

    MLIBOBJECTS = LIB/utils/utils.o \
    LIB/stats/stats.o \
    LIB/results/results.o \
    LIB/evaluate/evaluate.o \
    LIB/Chain/Chain.o  \
    LIB/Perceptron/Perceptron.o  \
    LIB/tagger_light/Tlight.o \
    LIB/examples/examples.o \
LIB/features/features.o 


    OBJECTS = sst-light.o \
LIB/utils/utils.o \
LIB/stats/stats.o \
LIB/results/results.o \
LIB/evaluate/evaluate.o \
LIB/Chain/Chain.o  \
LIB/Perceptron/Perceptron.o  \
LIB/tagger_light/Tlight.o \
LIB/examples/examples.o \
LIB/features/features.o #\
     #  /usr/local/WordNet-2.1/lib/libWN.a

    PEROBJ  = Perceptron/Perceptron.o  Perceptron/Kernel_Perceptron.o
    CRFOBJ  = CRF/CRF.o

    SuperSenseTagger: $(OBJECTS) 
        g++ $(OBJECTS) -o sst

    videotagger: $(MLIBOBJECTS) videotagger.o
      g++ $(MLIBOBJECTS) videotagger.o -o videotagger

    to-conll: to-conll.o
       g++ to-conll.o -o to-conll

    libwnss.so:     $(MLIBOBJECTS)
g++ -shared -o libwnss.so  $(MLIBOBJECTS) -lm -lpthread -lc -lstdc++ -lgcc_s

    .PHONY: clean

    clean:
      find . -name '*.[od]' -print -exec rm {} \;
    clean_bak:
      find . -name '*~' -print -exec rm {} \;

    # this command tells GNU make to look for dependencies in *.d files
    -include $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(SOURCES:%.cc=%.d))
```

On execution I get the following:

```
g++ -g -O1 -DPIC -fPIC -ILIB -I. -fno-exceptions   -c -o sst-light.o sst-light.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.3/ext/hash_map:64,
                 from LIB/examples/../tagger_light/../results/../utils/../hash_stuff/hash_stuff.h:26,
                 from LIB/examples/../tagger_light/../results/../utils/utils.h:31,
                 from LIB/examples/../tagger_light/../results/results.h:29,
                 from LIB/examples/../tagger_light/Tlight.h:29,
                 from LIB/examples/examples.h:19,
                 from sst-light.cpp:21:
/usr/include/c++/4.3/backward/backward_warning.h:33:2: warning: #warning This file includes at least
one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date.
Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of 
replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.
In file included from LIB/examples/../tagger_light/../results/../utils/utils.h:31,
                 from LIB/examples/../tagger_light/../results/results.h:29,
                 from LIB/examples/../tagger_light/Tlight.h:29,
                 from LIB/examples/examples.h:19,
                 from sst-light.cpp:21:
LIB/examples/../tagger_light/../results/../utils/../hash_stuff/hash_stuff.h: In member function
    âbool std::equal_to<const char*>::operator()(const char*, const char*) constâ:
LIB/examples/../tagger_light/../results/../utils/../hash_stuff/hash_stuff.h:44: error: â::strcmpâ has not been declared
make: *** [sst-light.o] Error 1
```

Anyone got any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: You forgot the `-Wall` flag for `g++` in your `Makefile` (which you should improve).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - gcc has updated their compiler and it is not 'default including' some header files it used to with older versions - The code you are using has not been updated to reflect this.

Looks like you need to add include for strcmp in sst-light.cpp

```
#include <cstring>
```

Also it looks as the code is using the old style of C++ include - so change things like

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

to

```
#include <iostream>
```

But only do this for the C++ header files.

Answer (score 1):

Open `/sst-light-0.4/LIB/hash_stuff/hash_stuff.h` and add this:

```
#include <cstring>
```

I also added the flag `-Wall` to the Makefile (not sure if it helps):

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -O1 -DPIC -fPIC -ILIB -I.
```

To run `sst`:

```
./sst
```